# forms which can apply conditions for individual fields in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I need a form with html created fields with values of a model. I've created one with createview concept.But in one field of drop down list I don't want to display the items with the Boolean available is false.In generic view concept I am unable to give the condition for a single field.How can I do this.

Comment: Please describe the problem in detail, or put the code

Comment: I would like to know how to create forms other than using generic view.In a particular field (dropdown) of the form I want to display those items with Boolean field called available is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model field add limit_choices_to

```
brand = models.ForeignKey("products.Brand",limit_choices_to={'is_deleted': False})
```

#

This part is for your comment

[image]

Do just like above image

Comment: what should I do to give a separate label from model fields to the form and  to apply form-control to the form fields   @SOBIR N

Comment: labels = {
            "brand" : "My Brand List"
        } add this to your model form like you add widget.

Comment: Check the answer above.